# Server security issue

Tags: security, file-upload, permissions, server, user-permissions

I'm developing a site on a local server on my machine.

In this site when the admin logs in they are to be allowed upload a file to the server.

Currently I am logging into the site as admin and attempting to upload the file, however I can only upload when the permissions are set to 777 (NOT GOOD) and can't do the same with 775 or 755.

Is this just a case of adding the site's admin name to the same group as is admin on the server?

Sorry pretty new to this jazz, hence the ignorance!
Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers!

These are the current settings

[image]

Comment: Which web server? Apache?

Comment: yeah its apache2 I'm running off a debian OS (had to switch from Ubuntu for other reasons)